# Joining a HashSet into a LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, hashset

I have a HashSet containing a list int int ids for items which must be selected.

```
HashSet<int> SelectedItems = new HashSet<int>()
```

The complete list of items is loaded by a LINQ to SQL statement.
I will be populating an ObservableCollection of the following:

```
public class DataItem
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public name String { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

The IsSelected property must be set to true if the Id is in the HashSet, otherwise it must be set to false;

Here is my LINQ query:

```
var items =
    from c in itemsContext.DataItems
    where (c.Latest == true)
    select c;
```

How can I join the HashSet into the above query to achieve the result I desire?

Thanks

PS: I am sorry but I do not know why the code blocks have been formatted incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i'm understanding your question properly i.e. dataitems corresponding to selecteditems in memmory...
Then use contains...

```
from dataItem in context.DataItems
where dataItem.Latest && SelectedItems.Contains(dataItem.Id)
select dataItem;
```

Comment: Almost what I needed, see below for what I cam up with.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with as a solution:

```
from dataItem in context.DataItems
where dataItem.Latest
select new {dataItem.Id,dataItem.Name,IsSelected=SelectedItems.Contains(dataItem.Id)};
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: this will enumerate the entire dataset of dataItems from the db, my understanding was that to filter the dataitems on the db.. cheers

Comment: The dataset will be filtered based on the Latest field being set. The HashSet membership is a requirement of the result set not the filter. Apologies if I was not clear enough.